# Matriz com índice fora de alcance retornando valores corretos

Tags: c, array, matriz

Estava tentando criar uma matriz utilizando `while` e percebi que o programa exibe todos os elementos corretamente se eu apenas incrementar o valor de `j` (coluna) até `8`. Não era para o programa imprimir valores aleatórios, já que são apenas 3 colunas?

```
int main(){
    int m[3][3]={10,2,3,
                4,5,6,
                7,8,9};
    
    int j = 0;
    while(j < 9)
    {
        printf("%d\n", m[0][j]);
        j++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Na verdade já existe um erro ao declarar uma matriz 3x3 atribuindo os valores apenas na posição 0xN, a declaração deveria ser da seguinte forma para que tenha efetivamente as duas dimensões da matriz: `int m[3][3] = { {10,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9} };`

Comment: @bruno101 Não tem problema nenhum inicializar o array daquela maneira. [Veja aqui](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization) no segundo exemplo da seção "nested arrays". Ver também [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/523935/112052) que mostra que no fundo as dimensões são apenas uma "ilusão" :-)

Answer (score 4):

Em C e C++ arrays bidimensionais nativos são guardados como zonas contínuas de memória, tal como se um array normal se tratasse. Nesse sentido, a figura que se segue ilustra isso mesmo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acima do array coloquei a posição que nos esperamos interpretar como um array bidimensional, e na parte de baixo coloquei a posição que irá ocupar na memória face ao espaço alocado. **Como vê a alocação coincide com a de um array simples de 9 posições**.

O pormenor neste tipo de arrays em C tem a ver com o que o compilador faz em cada acesso. Ele troca a notação `[linha][coluna]` por um acesso numa zona contínua de memória fazendo o seguinte cálculo:

```
<linha> * <quantidade de elementos de cada linha> + <coluna>
```

Significa que quando você quer aceder à linha 2 e coluna 1 com:

```
m[2][1]
```

Ele faz: `2 * 3 + 1` que lhe dá 7,e por isso essa é a posição de memória
a aceder correspondente ao `[2][1]` como vê na figura que coloquei.

Isto significa que apesar de você ter declarado o array erradamente e ter acedido erradamente, **ambos os erros jogam certo com a disposição dos elementos na memória internamente e por isso você vê os valores corretos**.

Seria diferente se tivesse feito um array de arrays através de ponteiros e alocação com `malloc`. Nessa situação este efeito não se iria verificar e teria visualmente o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Utilizando alocação dinâmica conseguiria ter esta disposição em memória com o seguinte código:

```
int **n = malloc(sizeof(int*) * 3);
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
    n[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);
}
```

E neste caso os acessos que está a fazer iriam efetivamente mostrar lixo na memória a partir da 4 posição acedida.

[Confirme você mesmo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/RRkz5p)

## Conclusão

Apesar de você ter feito errado, viu o resultado certo por coincidência de detalhes internos de disposição em memória. Isto é típico em C e é um dos pormenores que torna a linguagem mais difícil.

Noutras linguagens como Java ou C# nem nunca chegaria a ver este efeito pois acessos fora dos limites geram exceções, e por isso o erro seria detetado de imediato.

No código que tem o compilador avisa-lhe do erro de declaração incorreta do array, mas o de acesso fora dos limites não. Esse no entanto seria possível de detetar com uma ferramenta como o valgrind.

Answer (score 1):

Importante para entender o que está acontecendo: A memória do `array` é armazenada de forma sequencial no computador.

---

Então quando você usa `matrix[0][6]` ele parte do inicio do matrix até a sétima posição. A prova é, que se você fizer `matrix[0][12]` ele vai acessar a décima terceira posição, que é uma posição com lixo de memória.

---

E quando você faz o acesso no primeiro index como `matrix[index][0]` e como se você pulasse o tamanho usado na declaração index vezes. Exemplo:
`array[2][0]` na declaração que você fez é igual a `matrix[0][6]`.

Comment: Então é como se um array [3][3] e um [0][8] fizessem a mesma função?

Comment: Eu estava editando a resposta quando você comentou, acho que melhorei a explicação, e também responde a sua pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Você tem boas respostas acima.

Mas vou deixar um exemplo em C disso na prática e que talvez ilustre melhor essas coisas

> Estava tentando criar uma matriz utilizando `while` e percebi que o programa exibe todos os elementos corretamente se eu apenas incrementar o valor de j (coluna) até 8. Não era para o programa imprimir valores aleatórios, já que são apenas 3 colunas?

C não é FORTRAN. Em C não existem matrizes ou esse lance de vetores multi-dimensionais.

Em C existem apenas vetores. E vetores de vetores. E vetores de vetores de vetores. E assim por diante.

Os dados são gravados por linha. um depois da outra. Tudo que existe é o endereço de início e o cálculo a partir dos índices para achar o elemento. Só existe base e deslocamento, um endereço e um valor. E essa é a fórmula geral:

[image: A fórmula geral]

#### Um exemplo em C

Ao invés de um vetor `int[3][3]` como em seu programa vou usar um `char[12]` para mostrar a mecânica: 12 é múltiplo de 2, 3, 4 e 6 afinal. Não vou usar mais de 2 índices porque ficaria mais longo a toa. A fórmula acima mostra a conta para qualquer número de índices: `base(ar)` é o endereço inicial do array, `esize` é o número de colunas. A fórmula está em todo lugar, mas essa imagem foi copiada de [Data Structures Using C, Tenenbaum e outros, '89](https://www.amazon.com.br/Data-Structures-Using-Aaron-Tenenbaum/dp/0131997467) Um livro texto usado em toda parte.

#### O programa

O código a seguir usa esse vetor

```
    char        x[13] = "0123456789AB"; // 12+1
```

E acessa em seguida como vetores 2x6, 3x4, 4x3 e 6x2 , alterando o nono elemento para `'0'`, `'1'` e `'2'` no vetor `char[]` e mostrando o efeito nas outras "matrizes"

#### a saída do programa

```
x[8] = '0' = 48 (dec)
x_26[1][2] = '0' = 48 (dec)
x_34[2][0] = '0' = 48 (dec)
x_43[2][2] = '0' = 48 (dec)
x_62[4][0] = '0' = 48 (dec)

x[8] = '1' = 49 (dec)
x_26[1][2] = '1' = 49 (dec)
x_34[2][0] = '1' = 49 (dec)
x_43[2][2] = '1' = 49 (dec)
x_62[4][0] = '1' = 49 (dec)

x[8] = '2' = 50 (dec)
x_26[1][2] = '2' = 50 (dec)
x_34[2][0] = '2' = 50 (dec)
x_43[2][2] = '2' = 50 (dec)
x_62[4][0] = '2' = 50 (dec)
```

#### O código C

O programa tem só 20 linhas, serve apenas para mostrar como endereçar isso em C e como o que existe é apenas base e deslocamento.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int         main(void){
    char        x[13] = "0123456789AB"; // 12+1
    char      (*x_26)[2][6] =  NULL;
    char      (*x_34)[3][4] =  NULL;
    char      (*x_43)[4][3] =  NULL;
    char      (*x_62)[6][2] =  NULL;

    x_26 = x_34 = x_43 = x_62 = x;
    for ( int i='0'; i<'3'; i+=1)
    {
        x[8] = i;
        printf( "\nx[8] = '%c' = %d (dec)\n", x[8], x[8]);
        printf( "x_26[1][2] = '%c' = %d (dec)\n", (*x_26)[1][2], (*x_26)[1][2] );
        printf( "x_34[2][0] = '%c' = %d (dec)\n", (*x_34)[2][0], (*x_34)[2][0] );
        printf( "x_43[2][2] = '%c' = %d (dec)\n", (*x_43)[2][2], (*x_43)[2][2] );
        printf( "x_62[4][0] = '%c' = %d (dec)\n", (*x_62)[4][0], (*x_62)[4][0] );
    }
    return 0;
};
```

Essa é a linha importante:

```
    x_26 = x_34 = x_43 = x_62 = x;
```

Como todos são ponteiros para o mesmo endereço, mudando as dimensões dos vetores muda a fórmula acima, mas a soma sempre vai dar 8 :) e, como a base também é sempre a mesma, todos os ponteiros apontam para a mesma coisa.

Eis as contas:

Para `char x[12]`: `x[8]` vai estar em `*(x + 8)`, deslocamento 8 a partir de `x`

Para `char x[2][6]`: `x[1][2]` vai estar em `*(x + 1*6 + 2)`, deslocamento 8 a partir de `x`

Para `char x[3][4]`: `x[2][0]` vai estar em `*(x + 2*4 + 0)`, deslocamento 8 a partir de `x`

Para `char x[4][3]`: `x[2][2]` vai estar em `*(x + 2*3 + 2)`, deslocamento 8 a partir de `x`

Para `char x[6][2]`: `x[4][0]` vai estar em `*(x + 4*2 + 0)`, deslocamento 8 a partir de `x`

OK, é ruim de ler, mas pode ver a fórmula em efeito. E como declarar essas coisas em C.

Answer (score 0):

insira o código aquiNa verdade sempre tem o lixo de memoria, se você quiser imprimir corretamente recomendaria fazer 2 for (no caso você esta andando apenas a coluna) para imprimir seria algo assim:

```
int i=0,j=0;
for(i; i < 3 i++){
   for(j; j < 3; j++){
   printf("%d ",m[i][j]);
   
   }
   print("\n");
}
```

Comment: pois é. Mas nesse caso do codigo meu, ele está imprimindo todos valores corretamente (já alterei os valores pra testar) e queria entender pq isso dá certo,já que é como se ele estivesse percorrendo 9 colunas e uma linha como se fosse um vetor.

Comment: É meio complexa a explicação mas a memoria do computador é sequencial, quando você faz a matriz é uma forma de facilitar a visualização, porem na memoria física esta sequencial, o problema pode vir a ser quando é muito grande a informação, onde pode pegar outra parte do código em outra parte da memoria, se facilitar eu desenho

Comment: então teoricamente é como se a matriz realmente fosse um vetor com 9 elementos para o computador

Comment: Sim, porem é possivel que fique em outra parte do programa se for muito grande, uma forma pratica de você ver é com ponteiro, quer que eu lhe ensine como fazer?

Comment: estou aprendendo aos poucos, ainda não cheguei nos ponteiros mas obrigado pela explicação

Comment: cara, se precisar pode me chamar no whats, me formei a pouco tempo em ciencia da computação, pode ser que eu ajude um pouco kkkkk 11913180308

Answer (score 0):

Isso ocorre porque você não está preenchendo uma matriz da forma correta, o correto seria:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int m[3][3] = {         {10,2,3},          {4,5,6},          {7,8,9}     };

    int i=0,j=0;

    for(i; i < 3 i++){
       for(j; j < 3; j++){
       printf("%d ",m[i][j]);
       
       }
       print("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Na verdade eu já preenchi a matriz usando esse colchete entre os números e o resultado foi o mesmo. Eu sei que esse método com o For funciona, mas queria entender porque não dá erro quando eu uso o método que utilizei no código.