# Como transformar uma Array 2D em Pointer 2D em C

Tags: c, array, ponteiro, conversão-de-tipo

É possível uma função receber como parâmetro uma referência ao endereço de uma array bidimensional (matriz) estática, e a partir do ponteiro acessar os elementos dessa matriz.

No exemplo abaixo quando tento calcular o determinante da matriz A, a função `findDet(double **arr1)`, não consegue iterar, e o código gera o erro de Segmentation Fault:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double findDet(double **arr1){
    int det = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
      det = det + (arr1[0][i]*(arr1[1][(i+1)%3]*arr1[2][(i+2)%3] - arr1[1][(i+2)%3]*arr1[2][(i+1)%3]));
    }
    return det;
}

int main()
{
    double determinante;
    double A[3][3] = {{5, 2, 4}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 2, 5}};
    determinante = findDet(A);

    printf("%f", determinante);
    printf("Programa finalizado");
    return 0;
}
```

Sei que consigo consertar mudando a maneira em que recebo o parâmetro na função `findDet()` :

```
#include <stdio.h>

double findDet(double arr1[3][3]){
    int det = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
      det = det + (arr1[0][i]*(arr1[1][(i+1)%3]*arr1[2][(i+2)%3] - arr1[1][(i+2)%3]*arr1[2][(i+1)%3]));
    }
    return det;
}

int main()
{
    double determinante;
    double A[3][3] = {{5, 2, 4}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 2, 5}};
    determinante = findDet(A);

    printf("%f", determinante);
    printf("Programa finalizado");
    return 0;
}
```

Acho que isso acontece porcausa da diferença dos tipos.

Não queria ter que mudar o cabeçalho da função `findDet()`, é possível trasnformar minha variável do tipo `double A[3][3]` em `double **A`, antes de passar como parâmetro para minha função?

Se eu conseguir fazer essa transformação, minha função deve rodar sem problemas, certo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O pormenor fundamental é que `double A[3][3]` não é um array de arrays internamente, e sim um zona contínua de memória acedida de forma especial. Por esse motivo quando vai tentar aceder dentro da função imaginando que tem um `double**` como um ponteiro para um ponteiro o código falha.

Veja a minha resposta na pergunta [Matriz com índice fora de alcance retornando valores corretos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/523935/82711) para perceber melhor o problema.

Tem duas soluções para este problema:

## Alterar parâmetro da função

Esta é a solução que você propôs, e na minha opinião, é a mais simples e melhor para o código que tem. Se o problema é o de forçar a dimensão na função, pode evita-lo tornando a definição do tamanho dinâmica, assim:

```
double findDet(int linhas, int colunas, double arr1[linhas][colunas]){
```

Depois na chamada à função passa a poder definir a quantidade de linhas e colunas que o array tem:

```
determinante = findDet(3, 3, A);
```

Isto permite que a função possa ser usada em arrays com dimensões diferentes sem ter de a alterar.

[Veja a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/Ktdlrn)

Note que os dois parâmetros extra de linhas e colunas são necessários para que o compilador consiga fazer os cálculos internos de acesso ao array.

## Alterar a declaração do array

Se trocar a declaração e inicialização do array para uma alocação dinâmica com `malloc` pode efetivamente criar um array de arrays para que a função funcione como está, com o `double **arr1`.

Isto naturalmente faz com que o código de criação do mesmo seja muito mais extenso e que seja necessário eliminar de memória quando já não for útil, com recurso à função `free`.

Isso seria feito assim:

```
double **A = malloc(sizeof(double*) * 3);
A[0] = malloc(sizeof(double) * 3);
A[1] = malloc(sizeof(double) * 3);
A[2] = malloc(sizeof(double) * 3);
A[0][0] = 5;
A[0][1] = 2;
A[0][2] = 4;
A[1][0] = 1;
A[1][1] = 2;
A[1][2] = 3;
A[2][0] = 2;
A[2][1] = 2;
A[2][2] = 5;
```

[Veja a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/3aGuNs)

Pode alterar a declaração de cada linha para ser feita através de um `for` mas não vai poupar muito código. Se os valores forem lidos da consola ou arquivo, este código reduz-se bastante ficando apenas as alocações.

Comment: Então vou ter que recorrer a alocação dinâmica de memória para alterar a declaração do array! Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Em C uma matriz é lida como um vetor, e quando você tenta usar um ponteiro duplo, ele acaba buscando um endereço de memória que não esta alocado para seu vetor.

```
int matriz[2][2] = {{1,4},{3,7}}
/* é o mesmo que [1,4,3,7] */
```

Para corrigir seu acesso você precisa trabalhar com apenas uma posição no seu ponteiro.

```
int *ponteiro = matriz;
printf("%d\n", ponteiro[3]);
// escreve 7
```

Answer (score 0):

> Não queria ter que mudar o cabeçalho da função `findDet()`, é possível transformar minha variável do tipo `double A[3][3]` em `double **A`, antes de passar como parâmetro para minha função?

Sua variável do tipo `double A[3][3]` é do tipo que você declarou, `double[3][3]`, o que seu compilador pode te dizer. É um ponteiro e ocupa o que ocupa um `double*` em sua plataforma. Digamos 8 bytes para uma compilação em x64.

Sua variável do tipo `double **A` estaria melhor representada como `double**  A`, e é do tipo `double**`. É um ponteiro e ocupa o que ocupar um PONTEIRO para `double*`, os mesmos 8 bytes em x64.

Se está começando a programar nessa linguagem talvez deva declarar as coisas como são. Isso porque facilita a compreensão e a visualização e também ajuda  a interpretar as mensagens do compilador.

Quando você declara `double** A` está declarando `A`. Um nome. E declarando `A` como uma variável de um um tipo, `double**`.
Se `A` é `double**` então `*A` é `double*`, e `**A` é `double`. Isso é o resultado do operador `*` em C, o tal *dereferenCe operator* ou *indirection operator*. Isso é consequência da declaração e não a declaração.

> Se eu conseguir fazer essa transformação, minha função deve rodar sem problemas, certo?

Não. O que falta em seu caso é o tamanho. É preciso passar o tamanho. C não tem sequer matrizes como FORTRAN. Existem apenas tipos escalares e vetores. E vetores são representados por base + deslocamento. No seu modelo falta o deslocamento. Para "matrizes" existem vetores de vetores e vetores de vetores de vetores e assim por diante.

### Um exemplo dos tais ponteiros e a *transformação*

```
    double A[3][3];
    // agora uma "hierarquia"
    double   um_double = 42.;
    double*  pD   = &um_double;
    double** B = &pD;
```

Essa é uma representação mínima das coisas como declarou, A e B. Para ficar claro o que é o que veja como declarar e usar ponteiros para essas coisas:

```
    // um ponteiro para A
    double      (*pA)[3][3] = &A;
    // um ponteiro para B
    double***   pB = &B;
```

E usando isso para acessar `A[0][0]` ou `um_double`:

```
    A[0][0] = 42.42; // um exemplo
    A[2][2] = 84.84;
    // usando os ponteiros para acessar os dados
    printf("A[0][0] = %f (usando o ponteiro\n", (*pA)[0][0]);
    printf("Usando B para acessar o valor = %f\n", ***pB);
```

que mostra

```
A[0][0] = 42.420000 (usando o ponteiro
Usando B para acessar o valor = 42.000000
```

#### e a tranformação

```
    pD = (double*)A;
    printf("Usando B para acessar o inicio de A[][] = %f\n", ***pB);
```

mostra

```
Usando B para acessar o inicio de A[][] = 42.420000
```

E fica claro que `pB` aponta para o início de `A`. Só que a informação de indices se foi.

Além da base é preciso ter o deslocamento. Então só pode acessar o primeiro --- sem fazer as contas. E usar os índices não será aceito pelo compilador porque não tem essas informações.

#### Recuperando o deslocamento

```
    pA = (double(*)[3][3])pD;
    printf("Usando B para acessar A[2][2] = %f\n", (*pA)[2][2]);
```

Essa é a *transformação* de que falou. E mostra

```
Usando B para acessar A[2][2] = 84.840000
```

O valor esperado, depois de um cast para o formato correto. Mas só funciona se souber o tamanho e assim de nada adianta.

#### O programa todo

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    double A[3][3];
    // agora uma "hierarquia"
    double   um_double = 42.;
    double*  pD   = &um_double;
    double** B = &pD;

    // um ponteiro para A
    double      (*pA)[3][3] = &A;
    // um ponteiro para B
    double***   pB = &B;

    A[0][0] = 42.42; // um exemplo
    A[2][2] = 84.84;
    // usando os ponteiros para acessar os dados
    printf("A[0][0] = %f (usando o ponteiro\n", (*pA)[0][0]);
    printf("Usando B para acessar o valor = %f\n", ***pB);

    pD = (double*)A;
    printf("Usando B para acessar o inicio de A[][] = %f\n", ***pB);

    pA = (double(*)[3][3])pD;
    printf("Usando B para acessar A[2][2] = %f\n", (*pA)[2][2]);

    return 0;
};
```

#### A saída

```
A[0][0] = 42.420000 (usando o ponteiro
Usando B para acessar o valor = 42.000000
Usando B para acessar o inicio de A[][] = 42.420000
Usando B para acessar A[2][2] = 84.840000
```

Comment: Sobre a questão de eu não passar o tamanho, nesse programa só tem matrizes quadradas 3x3, mas obrigado por alertar. Conheço C a alguns anos, mas sempre fiz confusão com questões de ponteiros e com a utilização dos operadores `*` e `&`. Pelo o que eu tinha entendido da sua resposta se eu declarasse minha matriz estática dessa forma `double A[3][3]`, inicializasse os elementos, e em seguida criasse um ponteiro fazendo `double (*pA)[3][3] = &A`, eu estaria criando ponteiros que apontam para a minha Matriz, mas não conseguiria percorrer essa estrutura por causa da maneira que ela foi criada?

Comment: O programa que eu mostrei cobre os casos comuns, ida e volta eu acho. Como você disse agora conseguiria sim percorrer a matriz pelos índices, mas `pA` já tem embutido o tamanho da matriz e por isso eu disse que seria pouco útil. Uma solução comum seria encapsular a matriz em um typedef junto com as dimensões. Se são todas 3x3 e não precisa de nada genérico está bem assim como mostrei no final do exemplo